# How to download line item in Double Click Bid Manager API using R?

Tags: r, google-authentication, double-click, httr

I need to download line item on Double Click Bid Manager via API on R but I am getting a

```
Request failed [500]
Error: API returned: Backend Error
```

I am currently using the below R script to download line item in Double Click Bid Manager API.

```
item_request <- DownloadLineItemsRequest()

download_line_item <- lineitems.downloadlineitem(item_request)
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you try to look into your credentials to see if you have access to that download request?